# Thread stuck while creating socket in Java on RHEL 8.4

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Using following socket API to create a new socket where passing local address as null, local port as 0. Remote address and port are valid values. In some cases it get stuck in native API (trace shown below).

public class DsSocket
{
protected Socket m_socket;

```
 public DsSocket(InetAddress lAddr, int lPort, InetAddress address,
                int port, DsNetwork network) throws IOException
{
    this(new Socket(address, port, lAddr, lPort), network);
}
```

}

Comment: It is a blocking call. It will block until connection is established, or attempt is failed.
If the network is very slow or unreliable, then noticeable blocking is expected.
Depending on configuration, TCP may try to establish connection several minutes, before success or final timeout.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to reduce the connection time through tcp properties.